# C++: boost io_context/strand wrap causes segment fault on shared_ptr

Tags: c++, boost, segmentation-fault, shared-ptr

Could someone help me understand why I got the following result from the code snippet? If change the lambda function to take at least 1 parameter: I got output "valid ptr" twice. This was found in a segment fault crash I had in my code.

```
Output:
  valid ptr
  nullptr
```

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>

auto getWrapper(boost::asio::io_context& ioContext) 
{
    auto sharedPtr = std::make_shared<int>(0);
    return ioContext.wrap( [sharedPtr](){ 
                                          if(sharedPtr == nullptr) 
                                            std::cout << "nullptr\n";
                                          else
                                            std::cout << "valid ptr\n";
                                         });
}

int main()
{
    boost::asio::io_context ioContext;
    auto wrapper = getWrapper(ioContext);
    wrapper();
    wrapper();
    ioContext.run();
}
```

Comment: I am not really familiar with `boost::asio::context` but from my understanding it is meant to excute each operation once only. So probably the lambda is moved to the executor upon executing `wrapper()` the first time and leaving it in an empty state for the second execution.

Comment: I thought about that as well, if that is the case, shouldn´t the second execution of the handler cause run-timer error, e.g. std::bad_function_call? The wierd thing I observed is that everything seems to work if the lambda function take at least one arguments. Say ´return [sharedPtr](**int**){ ... }´

Comment: There aren't necessarily run-time checks. They just call the second call UB or something. At any rate the method `wrap` is deprecated. Consider using the alternative they suggest in the boosr documentation. Perhaps it isn't bugged. (The `int` version is probably wrapped by a layer of `boost::bind` wrapping which is moved to the execution - which is why the original lambda isn't moved).

Comment: Please don't forget to accept an answer if it helped you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you have to actually use a strand and `io_context::wrap` is deprecated.
So lets write

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>

auto getScheduleWrapper(boost::asio::io_context::strand& strand)
{
    auto sharedPtr = std::make_shared<int>(0);
    return [sharedPtr, &strand] () {
    boost::asio::post(strand.context(),
                      boost::asio::bind_executor(strand, [sharedPtr] (){
                          if(sharedPtr == nullptr)
                              std::cout << "nullptr\n";
                          else
                              std::cout << "valid ptr\n";
                      }));
        };
}

int main()
{
    boost::asio::io_context ioContext;
    boost::asio::io_context::strand strand{ioContext};
    auto scheduleWrapper = getScheduleWrapper(strand);
    scheduleWrapper();
    scheduleWrapper();

    ioContext.run();
}
```

This will output

```
valid ptr
valid ptr
```

as expected. But note: strands are not guaranteeing that scheduled tasks will run once, when in fact you are scheduling them twice. They are "only" guaranteeing that only one task will be running at a time on that strand, and that they will run in the order as they were originally scheduled.

Comment: Thanks, boost::asio::bind_executor does the job. It seems `return boost::asio::bind_executor(...)` is enough.

Comment: Why was wrap deprecated? What should I do if I _do_ need to wrap the execution? bind_executor just associates the executor by means of static typing.. For instance, I need to ensure that the initiation of async_initiate needs to run inside of a strand...

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb Its deprecated because the docs/library say so ("io_context::wrap (Deprecated: Use bind_executor.)"). And why do you need to "wrap" the execution? To make sure something "needs to run inside of a strand"? Why not just use a strand as described above?